# Xamarin forms ios multi platform app crash, the android version is working perfectly fine, the ios crashes on startup

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, multiplatform

```css
2019-03-22 14:46:35.302793-0300 CHA.iOS[14335:167957] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3698.93.8/UITableView.m:2062
2019-03-22 14:46:35.349720-0300 CHA.iOS[14335:167957] Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (19), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).
Native stack trace:
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001022331bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f345735 objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102232f42 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
 3   Foundation                          0x0000000102e63877 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 194
 4   UIKitCore                           0
x0000000118291e2d -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 18990
 5   UIKitCore                           0x00000001182ab711 -[UITableView endUpdates] + 75
 6   CHA.iOS                             0x0000000101ab6c19 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217
 7   ???                                 0x00000001353e2410 0x0 + 5188232208
```

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace CHA.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
}
```

My xamarin ios app crashes and it throws an exception in the main.cs which I caught using try n catch and this is the error "Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (19), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).
Native stack trace:".      The Android version works perfectly fine. I cleaned and rebuild the code, my Appdelegate folder build is already set to combile,

I have Clean, build and rebuild project
I have Set appdelegate folder build action to combile
I have Have commented out any code in the page that displays data on the screen

Comment: You can provide the code about the listview.It seems that there is something wrong in it.

Comment: Thank you @LucasZhang-MSFT, you pointed me in the right direction and I have narrowed the error down, these are the pages that are making the app crash, I am gonna add them in the questions snippet

Comment: Can you share your sample?

Comment: Yes sure, this was the code that was crashing the app on ios, it works when running it on the emulator but crashes after I stop debugging and try to run the app on an the emulator.  IEnumerable<AdvantageMember> benefits = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<AdvantageMember>>(json);
                        await store.UpdateItemsAsync(benefits);

Comment: This code crashes the app when I try to run in the background after stoping the emulator only on IOS,I am trying to insert the items into the sqlLite Db, so the will ....await Db.InsertAllAsync(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<AdvantageMember>>(json)).ContinueWith(async t =>
                        {
                            await store.UpdateItemsAsync(Db.QueryAsync<AdvantageMember>("SELECT * FROM AdvantageMember GROUP BY Title").Result);
                        });